# Head waits for full stdin before printing

Tags: linux, command-line, ls, stdin, head

When one runs

```
ls | head
```

head seems to wait for the full output of the piped command before printing to screen. This is undesirable when the command will take a very long time to run, such as when you are running ls on a directory containing millions of files.

However, when one runs

```
find | head
```

head does NOT wait for the full output before starting to print to screen - it does it in what appears to be real time.

My question is this: What is the difference between find and ls that causes this difference in behaviour? Secondly, is there a replacement command (for either ls, OR for head) that would allow me to instantly take the head of a long directory listing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `head`'s fault; it's `ls`'s. 
`ls` almost always sorts its output (by default, by name; if requested, by date). 
And it is in the nature of any sort that it cannot produce any output
until it has read the entire input. 
`find` does not sort its output, so it can start producing faster.

You could have seen this for yourself simply by running

```
ls
```

and

```
find
```

and observing the difference in response time.

BTW, you can get `ls` to list directories without sorting by specifying `-U`.

Comment: I think `ls -f` would request unsorted output?

Comment: Yes, `ls -f` also requests unsorted output. It also forces the `-a` option. I vaguely recall encountering a version of `ls` in which `-f` didn't work (I think it was defined to be something else) but `-U` did (but I don't remember where that was, and I may just be remembering wrong). And, come to think of it, I guess I've heard that `-U` isn't accepted everywhere.